# Preventing Thunderbird to add .txt to attachments on open

Tags: thunderbird, attachments

How can I prevent Thunderbird to add the extension .txt to a file when open the attachment. I have the problem with .patch files which I want look with notepad++. The problem is that notepad++ does not detect the right formating for the file because the extension is .txt.

If I drag the file on the desktop an double click all is working. Why change Thunderbird the file name on opening?

I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you seen if the .txt appears if sent to another email client?

Comment: Outlook does not do it. And a web mailer like Google also does not change the name of the attachment on open it.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [OpenAttachmentByExtension](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/OpenAttachmentByExtension-for-ThunderBird.shtml) solve my problem.